# Ruby - ActiveModel::SecurePassword not working

Tags: ruby, validation, passwords, activemodel

I have a simple ruby class with `ActiveModel::Validations` and `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` included, I provide all required attributes (below) to the new obkject but when I validate it it says it's `false`.

```
require 'active_model'
require 'bcrypt'

class User
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :password, :password_digest

  def initialize(name:, email:, password:)
    @name, @email, @password = name, email, password
  end
  
  validates :name, :email, presence: true
  has_secure_password
end

user = User.new(
          name: "TestUser1",
          email: "test@gmail.com",
          password: "password"
        )
```

`puts user.valid?`  => `false`

`puts user.errors.messages` => `{:password=>["can't be blank"]}`

`puts user.password` => `password`

According to the documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html#securepassword) `has_secure_password` provides validations on `password` accessor:

1. Password should be present.
2. Password should be equal to its confirmation (provided password_confirmation is passed along).
3. The maximum length of a password is 72 (required by bcrypt on which ActiveModel::SecurePassword depends)

What am I doing wrong? How's this object false?

***EDIT***
I have also tried adding `password_confirmation` attribute but it didn't work either.

`user.password_confirmation = "password"`

`puts user.valid?` => `false`

`puts user.errors.messages` => `{:password=>["can't be blank"]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to have `password_digested` filled by `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` you have to call `User#password=` [setter method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/InstanceMethodsOnActivation.html#method-i-password-3D). But it's not happening when you set your password using `@password = password` in your initializer. To fix it you have set it using `self.password = password`:

```
def initialize(name:, email:, password:) 
  @name, @email = name, email
  self.password = password
end
```

Also you need to remove `:password` from `attr_accessor` call because `SecurePassword` provides it.

Comment: It works. May I ask you, how did you know I needed to do `self.password = password`. Nowhere does the documentation say this and I would never figure that out.

Comment: Basically when I saw in documentation that when you assign `password` field you get `password_digest` field automatically filled with encrypted password I figured out that there should be overwritten `password=` method somewhere. Documentation doesn't really mention that because it works out of the box with ActiveRecord.

Comment: OK but this doesn't explain why one needs to do `self.password = password`. `password=` setter method is set in `attr_accessor` :password. I read the documention and examples and figured out that `password` attribute is added to the instance automatically by `has_secure_password` class method so I removed the attribute from my code and it works fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the user.password_confirmation attribute as well.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password

Comment: According to the documentation I linked I don't need to, however I have already tried that but it didn't work
user.password_confirmation = "password"
user.valid? => false